# Sqlite order by the many correct where statement

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i order by the sqlite query by its where clause.

for example:

```
--------------------------------------
| id |      body                     |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |the boy is going to bed        |
--------------------------------------
| 2  |the boy is good child          |
--------------------------------------
| 3  |the boy is playing the computer|
```

and my search input is:

```
"the boy is going to bed"
```

so my sql query will be.

```
select * from data
where body like '%the%' or like '%boy%' or like '%is%'
        or like '%going%' or like '%to%' or like '%bed%'
```

i want that the the id 1 is the first because its have a many correct where clause.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Ask exactly what you want.

Comment: i want to order my query by the count of its where statement.

Comment: e.g if your query has 6 where conditions, so the result of query should be of 6 words , not 5 right ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, the result of a boolean expression is just 0 or 1, so you can just add up these comparison expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE body LIKE '%the%'
   OR body LIKE '%boy%'
   OR body LIKE '%is%'
   OR body LIKE '%going%'
   OR body LIKE '%to%'
   OR body LIKE '%bed%'
ORDER BY (body LIKE '%the%'  ) +
         (body LIKE '%boy%'  ) +
         (body LIKE '%is%'   ) +
         (body LIKE '%going%') +
         (body LIKE '%to%'   ) +
         (body LIKE '%bed%'  )  DESC;
```